# Javascript won't read images

Tags: javascript, image, processing

I am working on an assignment at school and my teachers and I are stumped. I created a time based state machine in processing and am making that code work in javascript. However, I just keep getting a "loading..." screen when I run the code. It looks like (from viewing developer tools) that the server cannot read my image files. Any ideas/suggestions?

[Developer Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYCTP.png) &
[Images found in Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnP9D.png)

```
var iOne;
var iTwo;
var iThree;
var iFour;
var iFive;
var iSix;

var counter=30;
var state=0;

function preload(){
    iOne=loadImage("wall.jpg");
    iTwo=loadImage("screen.jpg");
    iThree=loadImage("mist1.jpg");
    iFour=loadImage("mist2.jpg");
    iFive=loadImage("mist3.jpg");
    iSix=loadImage("mist4.jpg");
}

function setup(){
    createCanvas(600,398);
}

function draw(){
    counter=counter-1;
    if(counter<0){
        state=state+1;
        if(state>14){
            state=0;
        }
        counter=30;
    }
    switch(state){
        case 0:
            image(iOne,0,0);
            break;

        case 1:
            image(iOne,0,0);
            break;

        case 2:
            image(iTwo,0,0);
            break;

        case 3:
            image(iThree,0,0);
            break;

        case 4:
            image(iTwo,0,0);
            break;

        case 5:
            image(iFour,0,0);
            break;

        case 6:
            image(iTwo,0,0);
            break;

        case 7:
            image(iFive,0,0);
            break;

        case 8:
            image(iTwo,0,0);
            break;

        case 9:
            image(iOne,0,0);
            break;

        case 10:
            image(iTwo,0,0);
            break;

        case 11:
            image(iOne,0,0);
            break;

        case 12:
            image(iTwo,0,0);
            break;

        case 13:
            image(iSix,0,0);
            break;

        case 14:
            image(iTwo,0,0);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What editor is that? It doesn't really matter what the editor says: the browser is the "ground truth" that you should focus on. It looks like you're running some kind of custom server, hence the long URLs with random characters in them. So I'd look at that as the first culprit. Unfortunately it's going to be next to impossible for us to help you with that, since we don't have access to that custom server. I don't notice anything obviously wrong in your code though. Btw, you might want to narrow your problem down to a [mcve]: we don't need to see `draw()` if the error is in `setup()`.

Comment: Where missing a function image(name,0,0) where is that function that bit must be drawing

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with paths. As long as you loading this images synchronously It may stuck at some error. Could u share your document tree and html content?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are accessing to your web using the "Run" button on your IDE. It will be easy to spot the error if you do like this:

1. As you are using JS and HTML only you don't need a web server, so paste your project folder on Desktop for example.
2. Open the main HTML, the one which is runnig that JS.
3. Now, if the error is still there you are going to see the same `404` but with a much more friendly path. The advantage of this is that now, you exact is searching for the image.
4. Adjust the correct path